# get property (width) from one element and assign to another one

Tags: javascript, properties, set, width, assign

I am trying to get the `width` property from one element and assign to another.

Here's my code (that does not work):

```
window.onload=function() {
    var morphWidth = document.getElementById('morph').width();
    var scrollbar = document.getElementById('scrollbar');
    scrollbar.style.width = morphWidth + "px";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use jQuery, then you can code like this:

```
var morphWidth = $('#morph').width();
```

If you use original Javascript, the you can code like this:

```
var morphWidth = document.getElementById('morph').offsetWidth;
```

jQuery object is different from DOM (Document Object Model).

The var `scrollbar` as same as.

Comment: `offsetWidth` is a **property**, not a method

Comment: @ToddMark Hmm, so shouldn't this work? (I'm loading jquery before):
window.onload=function(){
    var morphWidth = $('#morph').width();
    var scrollbar = $('#scrollbar');
    scrollbar.style.width = morphWidth + "px";
}

Comment: @Ian Thanks for that you correct this mistake, it has been changed.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the element width:

```
document.getElementById("morp").style.width;
```

and you can set the element width:

```
document.getElementById("morph").style.width="300px";
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I tried this and that and finally found a solution:

```
$(function() {
var morphWidth = $('#morph').width();
var scrollbar = $('#scrollbar');
$('#scrollbar').css('width', morphWidth + 'px');
});
```

However, I don't have a clue why this works now. Let me know if you do!